# Page url redirects to media file

Tags: php, wordpress

I did create a page called 'Tuinkamer' with slug '/tuinkamer' but when clicking on the link the page redirects to mediafile called 'tuinkamer.png' this is only on this single page. The whole website is working except for that specific page.

Does someone have any idea why the page is redirecting to a media file? I did not put anything in .htaccess or something.

https://www.metalura.bvdodev.nl/tuinkamer redirects to https://www.metalura.bvdodev.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/tuinkamer.jpg (404 page, I did delete the media file but it did not change anything)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try to flush your permalinks. (Go to Settings->Permalinks and click "Save Changes").

Comment: Seems to work fine this end?